# Электроlada? Электро-LADA?

Tags: слитно-раздельно, дефис, латиница-кириллица

Как писать такое, когда первая часть слова написана кириллицей, вторая – латиницей?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На этот счёт есть правило (см. [здесь](https://orfogrammka.ru/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9_%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B8_%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D1%83%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B2/)):

> 3. Дефис употребляется в составе письменных эквивалентов сложных слов, часть которых передается цифрой, буквой или буквами (в том числе нерусского алфавита) или иным начертанием (даже таким, которое невозможно «прочесть»), напр.: *25-процентный*, *150-летие*, *300-миллионный*, *5-1/2-тысячный*, *Т-образный*, *IBM-совместимый*, *γ-активный*, *«S-образное движение ловкого тела»* (Купр.), *ww-образные трубки*.

Таким образом, верно писать с дефисом: **электро-Lada** или же **электро-LADA**.

Comment: Но здесь латиница на первом месте...в приведенных примерах....

Comment: Да, но это не отменяет само правило, в котором говорится, что дефис ставится в составе сложных слов (то есть хоть в начале, хоть в конце или даже середине: NATO-ориентированный, анти-NATO, псевдо-NATO-блок — можно упражняться).

Comment: !!! Благодарю!!